# Why do I see AMD/ATI graphics driver updates when I have an Intel card (gma500)? What should I do with them?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, gma500

My system have gma500

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) (rev 07)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller (rev 07)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) HD Audio Controller (rev 07)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 07)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) USB UHCI #1 (rev 07)  
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) USB UHCI #2 (rev 07)  
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) USB UHCI #3 (rev 07)  
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) USB EHCI #1 (rev 07)  
00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) SDIO Controller #1 (rev 07)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) LPC Bridge (rev 07)  
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) IDE Controller (rev 07)  
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

But in the softwere updater (lubuntu 14.04) it shows update for

*X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver*
 *X.Org X server AMD/ATI Radeon display driver*

[image: Imgur]

What should I do, update them or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are simply drivers that are installed. Ubuntu ships with as many Open Source drivers as feasible by default, and this includes some drivers for various video, sound, and other devices which you may not have. It is perfectly fine to update them, or if you wish to free up a small amount of disk space, it is also safe to remove the AMD/ATI video driver packages.

You can remove the `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` and `xserver-xorg-video-ati` packages to remove the AMD/ATI drivers.

Comment: ok.. how to remove them

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a wide range of compatibility, and make things "easy", most distributions, including Ubuntu, included a large number of hardware drivers both in the kernel itself and in the graphical system (video and pointer drivers).

The kernel itself is "modular" and many drivers are not loaded unless they are needed. The same holds true for your graphical system.

In your case, you do not have an ATI card, so you are not using the driver.

Your options are to upgrade (probably best, will not hurt anything), ignore the upgrade (will not do any harm), or if you wish to micromanage what you have installed, build your own custom version of Ubuntu or another distro such as Arch.

Answer (score -1):

Your System Has both, have a look at the [Bumblebee Project](http://bumblebee-project.org/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with hybrid video systems. Also, no hybrid video enabled systems ever used the GMA500 (Poulsbo) chipset.

Comment: it has gma500 and not amd.

Comment: I disagree.  All hybrid video systems use some form of the Intel Chipset

Comment: @ECarterYoung Yes, but GMA500 was only used with Atom chips, and is not on any system that has hybrid graphics.